# Error while docker-compose: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

Tags: docker, macos, ubuntu, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to run ubuntu in docker and I am getting this error:

```
[+] Building 5.6s (9/9) FINISHED                                                                                                  
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                         0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 742B                                                                                         0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                            0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                              0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:latest                                                             0.0s
 => [1/5] FROM docker.io/library/ubuntu:latest                                                                               0.0s
 => [2/5] WORKDIR /ashdir                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [3/5] RUN apt-get update                                                                                                 3.9s
 => [4/5] RUN apt-get install -y                                                                                             0.7s 
 => [5/5] RUN apt install docker.io -y                                                                                       0.8s 
 => exporting to image                                                                                                       0.0s 
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                      0.0s 
 => => writing image sha256:90fb971dbc3eaef0932a0a669db821333e4e199625bb7169c0f307caab7f8807                                 0.0s 
 => => naming to docker.io/library/ubuntu                                                                                    0.0s 

Use 'docker scan' to run Snyk tests against images to find vulnerabilities and learn how to fix them
[+] Running 1/1
 ⠿ Container ubuntu-docker-ubuntu-1  Recreated                                                                               0.1s
Attaching to ubuntu-docker-ubuntu-1
ubuntu-docker-ubuntu-1  | Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
ubuntu-docker-ubuntu-1 exited with code 1
```

Here is the docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
    ubuntu:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        image: ubuntu
        ports:
            - 8091
        volumes:
            - ./ashdir:/ashdirrr
volumes:
    ashdir:
        external: false
```

Here is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
WORKDIR /ashdir
VOLUME /ashdir

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y

#RUN apt-get remove docker docker-engine docker.io
#RUN apt install docker.io
#RUN snap install docker
RUN apt install docker.io -y

EXPOSE 5000
#COPY . .
#CMD ["/bin/bash"]

#CMD echo ${environment}
#CMD echo ${cluster}
#CMD ["sh", "-c", "docker exec -it ${environment} ${cluster}"]
#CMD ["sh", "-c", "docker exec, "-it", "ubuntu", "/bin/bash"]
CMD ["sh", "-c", "docker exec -it ubuntu /bin/bash"]
#CMD ["docker exec -it ubuntu /bin/bash"]
#RUN docker exec -d -it ubuntu /bin/bash

#docker exec -it ubuntu /bin/bash
```

My objective is to up and run ubuntu in docker with just one command i.e., `docker-compose up --build`. That's why I am using CMD[] thing to run docker commands.
Any pointers on how to fix?

Comment: `CMD` should be `/bin/bash`, not this docker exec command.

Comment: Please run the command with sudo and check it again.

Comment: You should assume you can't run `docker` commands from inside a container, and design your application accordingly.  What's the actual thing you're trying to run in a container (it's almost never just "Ubuntu", what are you going to do with that base image)?